# Why is serial correlation a problem in GLMs?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, variance, autocorrelation

I have learned that serial correlation is a problem in linear regression as the idiosyncratic error terms are correlated which leads to the variance function of the coefficients to be misspecified and inefficient. The proof of this seems fairly straight forward, as shown by Ben Lambert on Youtube.

I was wondering, given that GLMs, aside from when data are continuous and a normal likelihood is used, don't have an idiosyncratic error, is serial correlation still a problem; and if it is, how can it be shown mathematically?

Comment: Yes, it is the same problem. Double each row and down go the standard errors of the coefficients.

Comment: I don't think you need the term "idiosyncratic".  Correlated errors are always a problem that needs to be accounted for. I don't know how to show it mathematically, but you can easily come up with examples - look for examples by googling "spurious correlation".  I don't see how it's any different for OLS regression and other GLMs.

Comment: @PeterFlom thank you for the response! I wrote idiosyncratic in linear regression each individual has an error that is minimised; whereas in nonlinear models, a function of a parameter of a probability distribution is specified without an error of this kind. Frank Harrell, and many others on this site, have said that nonlinear models do not have this idiosyncratic term, which is why I added it - maybe there is a misundertanding on my side. As such, I understand how, through this term, mispecification of the variance of the errors propages and causes problems in OLS, but not nonlinear models.